# How can a PhD in Machine Learning and AI help you in a life out of Academia?

Tags: phd, computer-science, industry

I have applied for a Ph.D. in Computer Science. I do not, however, plan to become an academic afterward. What I want to achieve is to try to commercialize my research by founding a startup or find a job outside of Academia, using the knowledge I will obtain for enhancing or building products/services for my employer.

What I would like ideally, is to achieve Academic as well as Industry expertise in machine learning and AI, through a job or by trying to found a startup with a related thematology. Becoming a professor is completely out of my goals. However, I want to be able to study academic literature with ease.

Do you think my goal is reasonable, or a Ph.D. is an overkill that would make me overqualified, losing precious time in case I change my mind in the future?

The reason I want the Ph.D. is to learn more things and receive more hands-on experience in Machine Learning. I believe that this process will also enhance my critical skills and analytical thinking.

I understand this can get difficult and risky but I am willing to try.

Does my goal make any sense or do I need a reality check? I need a hard critique...
Is that a healthy reason for attending graduate school?

Comment: In my place and field, it is quite usual for people to switch to the industry after receiving their doctoral degree. However, that does not mean it is just as usual and accepted in your place and field - some more context may be required. One thing that might be somewhat more generally true, though, is that if you indeed want to found a startup, doing a PhD can provide you with some precious time to prepare for that (i.e. develop a core product) and also some opportunities (possibly supported by the university) to build a network and learn about founding of startups.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's cross-posted on stats: see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Working at your startup**

One thing for sure is that, if you want to start a company (a *startup*), you should not be afraid of being overqualified, since you will be "the boss" and there is no one to classify you as such.

**Working in the industry**

While being overqualified sometimes (perhaps, even, often) applies to positions in the *industry*, a Ph.D. graduate is highly unlikely to be considered as such in ML/AI domain, where it is often a *requirement* for most positions.

**Working for other people's startup**

Even though most startups generally don't care about degrees, those, working in ML/AI-related domains, will be happy to consider and hire a good Ph.D. graduate for the obvious reason: due to relatively *high complexity* of the required ML/AI-related subject domain expertise.

**P.S.** Please note that my answer addresses only your concern of being overqualified, but does not touch a larger question of feasibility of your plan, factors to consider in decision making and so on. However, it implicitly suggests that this one of possible routes to achieve your goal (whether it's the best or the optimal one, depends on a lot of factors, including your personal circumstances).

Answer (score 2):

Both fields are currently "hot" and have several practical applications. Thinking IBM research, MS research, tableau.com, just to name the few that I've applied to... there is absolutely no shortage of jobs. If you interface that with big data, you should be ok for a few decades, at least...

Full disclosure: My phd was in image processing (well, not quite, but not ML either) and I'm currently changing my research area exactly because of that demand...

I know it is not on your plans, but just to be complete, that is even more true for professors and TT positions... cra.org has at least 1 new opening/day in those fields...

So yes, if you wanna work ML Research, a good PhD, with publications (think CVPR+) is *the* way to go.